# Hardcoding a reference to a template's image

Tags: php, wordpress-theming

I am working with WordPress, but I thought this question was more generic, so decided to post it here (please advise otherwise). I have the following function in my functions.php:

```
function get_thumbnail(){
    if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
        return get_the_post_thumbnail();
    } else {
        return "<img src='" . get_bloginfo('template_directory') ."/images/thisimage.jpg' alt='This Image'>";
    }
  }
```

I need to make the URL absolute, so I have re-written in this way:

```
function get_thumbnail(){
    if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
        return get_the_post_thumbnail();
    } else {
        return "<img src='http://mysite.co.uk/folder/images/thisimage.jpg' alt='This Image'>";
    }
  }
```

Is that correct?

Thank

Comment: The easiest way to know if it's correct is to try it. If it works, it's correct. But it does look correct.

Comment: yes, it actually works

Answer (score 0):

`get_site_url();` would be a better way to do it. Rather than hardcoding

```
function get_thumbnail(){
    if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
        return get_the_post_thumbnail();
    } else {
        return "<img src='" get_site_url()."/". get_bloginfo('template_directory') ."/images/thisimage.jpg' alt='This Image'>";
    }
}
```

This would stop you having to change your code if your site url changed

Comment: isn't the question the other way around? He has dynamic now but wants hard coded?

Comment: No. OP needed an **absolute** url

Comment: interesting and perhaps useful in the future, thanks